# Does an executable have the same file privileges as the user who ran it?

Tags: linux, unix, file-permissions, setuid

In Unix, if I run a binary which mucks around with files, does the binary have the same file permissions as myself (the user who ran the binary)?

Comment: Actually it is not the binary that has permissions, but the process. The process was started by a user. So the process inherits the _current_ rights, settings and environment of that users current shell. Whatever current means in a given situation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most of the cases, the answer is yes!

However this is not true if you have `setuid`, `setgid` bits enabled on that binary.

Classic example of binary with the `setuid` enabled.

```
ls -ltra `which passwd`
```

That command would not be able to work, if it could not grant you (the user that execute the command) the same privilege as root during its execution to modify files like `/etc/password` or `/etc/shadow`

Have a look at:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-4883/secfile-69/index.html

**setuid Permission**

> When set-user identification (setuid) permission is set on an
>   executable file, a process that runs this file is granted access based
>   on the owner of the file (usually root), rather than the user who is
>   running the executable file. This special permission allows a user to
>   access files and directories that are normally only available to the
>   owner.

**setgid Permission**

> The set-group identification (setgid) permission is similar to setuid,
>   except that the process's effective group ID (GID) is changed to the
>   group owner of the file, and a user is granted access based on
>   permissions granted to that group. The /usr/bin/mail command has
>   setgid permissions

You might also want to have a look at `fork` and `exec` if you want to dig a bit further into how does Linux manage processes and subprocesses.